# Why can't I find the index of the maximum value in my spectrogram array?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, spectrogram

I'm working with a spectrogram, and I want to find the index of the maximum value in that array at a certain frequency in a certain time range in order to tell when the maximum happens. I found the maximum and it was the value I expected from a plot of the data, however when I attempt to index the value I get an empty array no matter how hard I try.

This is my input code:

```
tindex=np.where((t-tprior>0)&(t-tprior<2))
tindex=np.array(tindex)

findex=np.where(freqs==72)
findex=int(findex[0])


echopeak = np.amax(-np.real(Xsum[findex,tindex]))
print(echopeak)

peakindex = np.where(Xsum == echopeak)
print(peakindex)
print(Xsum[peakindex])

print(abs(Xsum[findex,tindex]-echopeak)<=1e44)
```

And this is the output:

```
5.860244612305991e+44
(array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))
[]
[[False False False False False False False False False False False False
  False False False False False False False False False False False False
  False False False False False False False]]
```

Obviously, since the value was returned then it exists.

I have alternately tried:

```
peakindex = (abs(Xsum - echopeak) <= 1e-12) #with numbers ranging all the way up to 1e44
peakindex = (Xsum[findex,tindex] < echopeak+1e44)&(Xsum[findex,tindex] > echopeak-1e44)
```

Nothing returns the index of the maximum. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if this is the entire problem, but one issue is that you're trying to compare floats `Xsum == echopeak`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) returns the index of the maximum value in an array:

```py
peakindex = np.argmax(Xsum)
```